# Rails | Add condition in join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it possible, to add condition in join query?

For example I want to build next query:

```
select * from clients
left join comments on comments.client_id = clients.id and comments.type = 1
```

`Client.joins(:comments).all` generates only:

```
select * from clients
left join comments on comments.client_id = clients.id
```

PS. `Client.joins("LEFT JOIN comments on comments.client_id = clients.id and comment.type = 1")` isn't nice.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
Client.left_outer_joins(:comments)
  .where(comments: { id: nil })
  .or(Client.left_outer_joins(:comments)
    .where.not(comments: { id: nil })
    .where(comments: { type: 1 }))
```

what gives you something equivalent to what you want:

```
SELECT "clients".* 
FROM "clients" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" 
    ON "comments"."client_id" = "clients"."id" 
WHERE "comments"."id" IS NULL 
  OR ("comments"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "comments"."type" = 1
```

UPDATE

Actually, this does not work because rails close the parenthesis leaving outside the evaluation of type.

UPDATE 2

If yours comment types are few and is not probable its values will change, you can solve it with this way:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :new_comments,  -> { where comments: { type: 1 } }, class_name: Comment
  has_many :spam_comments, -> { where comments: { type: 2 } }, class_name: Comment
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
end
```

With this new relationships in your model now you can do:

```
Client.left_joins(:comments)
```

gives:

```
SELECT "clients".*
FROM "clients"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" 
    ON "comments"."client_id" = "clients"."id"


Client.left_joins(:new_comments)
```

gives:

```
SELECT "clients".*
FROM "clients"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments"
    ON "comments"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND "comments"."type" = ?  
/*[["type", 1]]*/


Client.left_joins(:spam_comments)
```

gives the same query:

```
SELECT "clients".*
FROM "clients"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments"
    ON "comments"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND "comments"."type" = ?  
/*[["type", 2]]*/


Client.left_joins(:new_comments).where name: 'Luis'
```

gives:

```
SELECT "clients".*
FROM "clients"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments"
    ON "comments"."client_id" = "clients"."id" AND "comments"."type" = ?
WHERE "clients"."name" = ?
/*[["type", 1], ["name", "Luis"]]*/
```

NOTE:

I try to use a parameter in the original has_many relationship like...

```
has_many :comments, -> (t) { where comments: { type: t } }
```

but this give me an error:

ArgumentError: The association scope 'comments' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```rb
      meals_select = Meal.left_outer_joins(:dish_quantities).arel
      on_expression = meals_select.source.right.first.right.expr
      on_expression.children.push(DishQuantity.arel_table[:date].eq(delivery_date))
      on_expression.children.push(DishQuantity.arel_table[:dish_id].eq(Dish.arel_table[:id]))
```

```
ON "dish_quantities"."meal_id" = "meals"."id" AND "dish_quantities"."date" = '2022-08-05' AND "dish_quantities"."dish_id" = "dishes"."id"
```

Comment: how is that nicer than `Client.joins("LEFT JOIN comments on comments.client_id = clients.id and comment.type = 1")`?

Answer (score -4):

```
Client.joins(:comments).where(comments: {type: 1})
```

Try this

Comment: It generates `select * from clients
left join comments on comments.client_id = clients.id where comments.type = 1`

Comment: yes...the way you have specified is an only way to add join with condition